# In Mongodb subdocument array is there any way to add a new field in each subcoument

Tags: arrays, mongodb, subdocument

Suppose i have a document like

```
{
    "_id" : 5,
    "rows": [
        { "id" : "aab", "value":100},
        { "id" : "aac", "value":400},
        { "id" : "abc", "value":200},
        { "id" : "xyz", "value":300}
    ]
}
```

and i need to add a new key in each sub document **"status" : 1** and result should be look like

```
{
    "_id" : 5,
    "rows": [
        { "id" : "aab", "value":100, "status":1},
        { "id" : "aac", "value":400, "status":1},
        { "id" : "abc", "value":200, "status":1},
        { "id" : "xyz", "value":300, "status":1}
    ]
}
```

How can i do this by single update query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo [positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) with `$elemMatch` having problem;

> The $ operator can update the first array element that matches multiple query criteria specified with the $elemMatch() operator.

So this case using mongo query you should update only specific matching criteria. If you set `rows.aac` in match then you will add `status:1` in `row.aac` array, check query as below :

```
db.collectionName.update({
  "_id": 5,
  "rows": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "id": "abc"
    }
  }
}, {
  $set: {
    "rows.$.status": 1
  }
}, true, false) // here you insert new field so upsert true
```

[mongo update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update) showing how `upsert` and `multi` works.

But still you want to updated all documents then you should use some `programming code` or some `script`. Below code update all data using [cursor forEach](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) :

```
db.collectionName.find().forEach(function(data) {
  for (var ii = 0; ii < data.rows.length; ii++) {
    db.collectionName.update({
      "_id": data._id,
      "rows.id": data.rows[ii].id
    }, {
      "$set": {
        "rows.$.status": 1
      }
    }, true, false);
  }
})
```

If your documents size more then better way to use [mongo bulk update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/#Bulk.find.update) below code shows how to updated using mongo bulk :

```
var bulk = db.collectionName.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var counter = 0;
db.collectionName.find().forEach(function(data) {
  for (var ii = 0; ii < data.rows.length; ii++) {

    var updatedDocument = {
      "$set": {}
    };

    var setStatus = "rows." + ii + ".status";
    updatedDocument["$set"][setStatus] = 101;
    // queue the update
    bulk.find({
      "_id": data._id
    }).update(updatedDocument);
    counter++;
    //  re-initialize every 1000 update statements
    if (counter % 1000 == 0) {
      bulk.execute();
      bulk = db.collectionName.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
  }

});
// Add the rest in the queue
if (counter % 1000 != 0)
  bulk.execute();
```